# Plugin Not Working After Being Uploaded To Wordpress Plugin Repository

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, uploads

Why my wordpress plugin is not working after I uploaded it to wordpress plugin repository. Is there any requirement of what tool I should use to write it or may be something else?

Here is my plugin repository http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/ind-css3-pricing-table/

Comment: which error message you getting when trying to activate plugin

Comment: Your plugin installs and activates fine, however there are runtime errors trying to use it. What exactly do you consider cause by plugin directory?

Comment: I tested the plugin that I took directly from my computer, and its jquery is working fine, but after I place it to the plugin folder that is the svn gateway and then uploaded it and installed it from the repository, the plugin's jquery won't work at all. It should hide the "Remove Column" button when there are only one column and it should also connecting some input fields with wp-colorpicker.

Comment: And what is different about the install from the repo than on your local machine?  Did a js file maybe not get included?

Comment: All included, but the wp enqueue scripts doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **have** to develop with [WP_DEBUG](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) enabled. And use Firebug or Chrome Console to check for Network/JavaScript errors.

[image]

WP is trying to locate the folder **`/wp-content/plugins/ind_css3_pricing_table`** and the correct is **`/wp-content/plugins/ind-css3-pricing-table`**

Comment: Owwwh.. my dumb.. I didn't pay attention to how wordpress repository write plugin's main folder. I should use " -" instead of " _" . Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can't assume that your plugin will be in either the `ind-css3-pricing-table` or `ind_css3_pricing_table` folders all the time.  This should not be hardcoded in your plugin.  Instead, you can determine the path or URL to your plugin folder using the `__FILE__` magic constant in your main PHP file.

```
$plugin_path = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__);
$plugin_url = plugins_url('', __FILE__);
```

Comment: Woops, I forgot to show an example...